# Is there a ListRowPresenter which uses VerticalGrid instead of HorizontalGridView?

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

As you know in leanback library there is a `ListRowPresenter` which presents its items via `HorizontalGridView`. (see its source [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/home-tomonori-ishizaki/Android-Support-Leanback-v17/master/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.java)) But can we have a Presenter using `VerticalGrid`?

I want the last row of my `BrowseFragment` becomes vertically scrollable (with how many rows as it need and fixed column number!) and instead of `setNumRows` I would write `setNumVolumns` ...

Is it possible in leanback?

---

**UPDATE 1 :**
In order to use a presenter in `BrowseFragmen`t, it should be a child of `RowPresenter`. `VerticalGridPresenter` is not so you can not use it in a browse fragment at all. I am looking for a something like `ListRowPresenter` which is built using `VerticalGridView`. (`ListRowPresenter` uses `HorizontalGridView`)

Comment: Have you found solution?, can you post it ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is a presenter called `VerticalGridPresenter` that exists for this purpose. It has a method `public void setNumberOfColumns(int numColumns)` to set the number of columns. If this does not suit your needs you will probably have to write a custom presenter.

Comment: In order to use a presenter in browsefragment, it should be a child of RowPresenter. VerticalGridPresenter is not so you can not use it in a browse fragment at all. I am looking for a something like `ListRowPresenter` which is built using VerticalGridView. (ListRowPresenter uses HorizontalGridView)

Comment: There is no such thing. A row is horizontal, so anything extending `RowPresenter` will be horizontal in nature. You are trying to fit a column into a row. It's not built for that. You might be able to achieve it by writing a custom `RowPresenter` yourself, but it wouldn't make much sense. An alternative could be to create your own implementation of `BrowseFragment` with support for a grid under the inner `RowsFragment`. Or you could simply put a `VerticalGridFragment` under your `BrowseFragment`.

Comment: It may make sense. Imagine the last row of browsefragment is full of content. so it is better to browse it vertically than horizontally! I was seeking for a written solution in somewhere if any. Anyhow thanks

Comment: @Saleh Did you arrive at any solution for this? I am looking for a similar kind of implementation. Your help would be appreciated.